# DELETE FROM WHERE Query not doing anything - SQLite C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to delete all the rows of a particular Aperture (of Bussiness) whenever the user clicks the button (which is a Save button), so to then insert the data to save. The code is the following:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteCommand cmdDel = new SQLiteCommand();
        cmdDel = SQLconnect.CreateCommand();
        cmdDel.CommandText = "DELETE FROM GridTable WHERE Aperturas=@combo";
        cmdDel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combo", combo1.Text);
        cmdDel.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)grid1.DataSource;

        string sql = "INSERT INTO GridTable (Aperturas, Ventas, Proveedores, EAE, EAM) VALUES (@aperturas,@ventas,@proveedores,@eae,@eam)";

        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
            cmd = SQLconnect.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aperturas", combo1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ventas", r["Ventas"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proveedores", r["Proveedores"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eae", r["Egreso Axel Efectivo"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eam", r["Egreso Axel Mercaderia"]);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }           
    }
```

the problem is that the delete function does not seem to do anything, when i load the data back it appears duplicated, as if it was inserted for a second time (which it was, but not to end up showing like that)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: cmdDel = SQLconnect.CreateCommand(); This line what is doing the place should not be here.

Comment: You are trying to delete the values `WHERE Aperturas=@combo`. Does `combo1.Text` have the correct value for everything you want to delete?

Comment: Not really sure what it does but if I just put DELETE FROM GridTable, then it does delete the whole table so I think that is not the problem @mybirthname

Comment: @JoaquinGuevara In that case, it sounds like the `WHERE` clause is the problem. Check the value of `combo1.Text`.

Comment: The ComboBox text is the same as when the datatable for the datagridview was first loaded, so it should be the correct value @Tot Zam

Comment: Use debug see the value for combobox.Text after that copy the query and execute it in the DB-> see result

Comment: A try/catch block can help you identify what's going wrong.

Comment: I think the `DELETE` is working just fine. It seems the issue is with your `DataTable`, which probably already have the duplicate rows in it.